# Does a ASP.NET WebAPI backport to .NET 2.0/3.5 already exist?

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, asp.net-web-api, .net-2.0

I have really enjoyed working with ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET WebAPI especially.

I have been unsuccessful in trying to find an existing ASP.NET WebAPI backport to .NET 2.0/3.5.  Does anyone in the SO community know of one that has already been done or one that needs a contributor?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't exist because of the required dependencies not to mention licensing issues in a third party redistributing a port of WebAPI.

Comment: WebAPI is now licensed under Apache 2, so derivative works are definitely possible.  Under the covers, the biggest challenge for the port is dealing with the async stuff.  Task is used heavily.